# Как получить разрешение экрана пользователя?

Tags: linux, c, gtk

В gtk никаких функций не вижу, может есть какой-то простой способ получить через системные функции разрешение экрана?

Answer (score 2):

```
GdkRectangle workarea = {0};
gdk_monitor_get_workarea(
    gdk_display_get_primary_monitor(gdk_display_get_default()),
    &workarea);

printf ("W: %u x H:%u\n", workarea.width, workarea.height)
```

[Оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225956/how-to-get-the-size-of-the-screen-with-gtk)